# Having Issue on Setting Array of $headers in PHP Mail Function

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I am not able to send email through PHP mail function while I specify an array of $headers as

```
$headers = array (
               'From' => "info@mysite.com",
               'Content-type' => "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
               );
```

or

```
$headers=array(
    'From: "info@mysite.com',
    'Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Reply-To: "info@mysite.com'
);
```

and here is the code

```
 <?php
   $email = 'test@test.com';
   $headers=array(
    'From: "info@mysite.com',
    'Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Reply-To: info@mysite.com'
);

$msg= 'This is a Test';

 mail($email, "Call Back Requert Confirmation", $msg, $headers);
?>
```

can you please let me know why this is happening? and how I can fix this?

Comment: send headers as string not an array

Comment: Hi, honestly I didnt try it

Comment: Use `join("\r\n", $headers)`.

Comment: Didn't try what? Reading the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send `$headers` through array, then you need to add `\r\n` to the end of each header value and convert the array into a `string`.

Your code should be:

```
$headers = array(
    'From: <info@mysite.com>',
    'Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Reply-To: <info@mysite.com>'
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks hardik but this code adding " before the email!

Comment: The address shouldn't be in quotes, it should `<info@mysite.com>`.

Comment: but what I am getting is "info@mysite.com

Comment: still on reply I am getting "info@mysite.com at email address! the " is not showing on receiving mail but shows up when reply!

Comment: according to the docs,since PHP 7.2,  `mail` should be able to accept an array for the `$headers` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`$headers` needs to be a string, not an array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers = 
    'From: info@mysite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"
;

mail($email, "Call Back Requert Confirmation", $msg, $headers);
```

If you want to keep `$headers` as an array, you can also do

```
mail($email, "Call Back Requert Confirmation", $msg, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 2):

try to send headers as string not an array

```
$headers = "From: info@mysite.com\r\n"; 
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers.= "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

or using array convert array in string using `implode()` and send it to `mail()`

```
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
mail($email, "Call Back Requert Confirmation", $msg, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 7.2.0 (released 2017-11-30)
the php `mail` function accepts an associative array
for `$additional_headers` -> [Example](https://www.php.net/mail#example-3093).