# php mail not sending the correct From header using cpanel

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a text message or an email that shows the supplied 'From' address.

```
$to         = 'phone number or email';
$headers    = array(
    'From'     => "noreply@site.com",
    'Reply-To' => "noreply@site.com",
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

'mail(
    $to,
    $subject,
    $message,
    $headers = [],
    $additional_params = ""
);'
```

When the text message or email is delivered, the from address shows something like: e3odhdrfh4h@textcpnl4324.prod.phx3.secureserver.net

I am running a WordPress website using Cpanel hosting. I am trying to make this work using the PHP mail function and not the wp_mail function.

thanks

Comment: You need to add `$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);`  You may refer to this [SO_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478307/having-issue-on-setting-array-of-headers-in-php-mail-function) .

Comment: What values of sendmail_from and sendmail_path parameters are setted in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
mail(
    $to,
    $subject,
    $message,
    implode("\r\n", $headers),
    "-fnoreply@site.com"
);
```

The last parameter (`additional_params`) with that `-f` will force to change the `Return-path` mail header and any server error sending the mail will go there instead `e3odhdrfh4h@textcpnl4324.prod.phx3.secureserver.net` in your case..